# how can I use make clean to delete unknown files?

Tags: makefile, delete-file

I wrote the following makefile:

```
include config.mk

DATA_FILES=$(wildcard ../*.dat)

all : plot output_data

.PHONY : plot
plot : output_data $(PLOT_SRC)
        $(PLOT_EXE)

.PHONY : output_data
output_data : $(SIM_SRC) $(DATA_FILES)
        $(SIM_EXE)

.PHONY : clean
clean :
        rm -f output_data
        rm -f plot
```

As i expected make clean is not working, the problem is that i don't know the name or the number of files that are going to be created during make. I know their extensions but I'd rather don't use wildcards+extension to avoid delete other files. Moreover, I know I could make the code print out the name of the files it gives as an output, but 1) the code is not mine, so I' prefer not changing it, and 2) the code is not just creating files, but a number of folders.
Any other options to delete all the files created that I didn't consider?

Comment: Where are the created files created? In the current directory? In the directory of the data? In a specific output directory?

Comment: all the files (and new folders) are created in the current directory where makefile is

Comment: The easiest thing to do here (assuming you have no way of knowing ahead of time (or from a generated list) what the created files are going to be) is to figure out a way to get them generated in a specific, per-instance, directory. (Something like `dir=$(mktemp -q -d -t 'makedir-XXXXX'); cp Makefile "$dir"; make -C "$dir"` where `Makefile` has been modified to assume `config.mk` is one directory higher up and the data is now two directories higher up, etc.)

Comment: If you were deleting files and folders by hand, how would *you* know which had been created by Make, and which had not?

Comment: The traditional approach to this problem is to build everything in the source directory and have an `install` target to copy all relevant files to their final destination, so you can completely remove the source directory afterwards.

Comment: One idea is to create a sentinel file at the start of the build and in the `clean` target use `find -newer` to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU make, the `filter-out` function may be a solution. Assuming you have a list of files and directories to keep in a make variable `KEEP`, you can:

```
KEEP = <list-of-files-and-directories-to-keep>

clean:
    @echo rm -rf $(filter-out $(KEEP),$(wildcard *))
```

Try to run this and, if satisfied, remove `echo`. Or, instead of `rm`, move the files and directories you do not want to keep in a temporary directory:

```
clean:
    @mkdir -p ../backups; \
    mv $(filter-out $(KEEP),$(wildcard *)) ../backups
```

and manually check the content of `../backups`.